how to do normalization i am failing to understand why the mean and variance arent getting applied
how the code should be working
my code:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Normalization 
normalizer = Normalization(mean= 5 , variance= 4) # normalization object 
normalized_tns1 = tf.constant([[3,4,5,6,7]])
print(normalized_tns1.shape)
print("\nOutput :\n")
normalizer(normalized_tns1)

The thing i am doing is same as above  image but when i am doing it i get the reshaping error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[88], line 7
      5 print(normalized_tns1.shape)
      6 print("\nOutput :\n")
----> 7 normalizer(normalized_tns1)

File c:\Users\Sujal07\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:122, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    119     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    120     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    121     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 122     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    123 finally:
    124     del filtered_tb

File c:\Users\Sujal07\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__Reshape_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Input to reshape is a tensor with 1 values, but the requested shape has 5 [Op:Reshape]

reshaping works but i dont want to do that as the matrix changes

I copy-pasted your code and it works for me providing the same result as on the image. I am on TF 2.15.0.

i am using tf 2.16.1 not  working there

thax saved time i tried on other version worked there

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
